# Image with xsl and Template inside Template

Tags: xml, image, xslt

I am trying to add pictures in a table in xml and xsl files. I have made research on the net and found this solution : [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187157/how-to-call-an-image-correctly-through-xsl-from-a-string-within-an-existing-xml).
However my problem is that I already have a template for my table. I tried the solution proposed by Don Roby (it is not working in my case) but because I tried to use a template inside another one it is not accepted.
So I would like to know if there is a speacial solution for my specific case or if I have just made some basic errors.

Here is my **XML** code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Employe.xsl"?>



<List_Of_Employe>



    <Employe>

        <ID> 1235 </ID>

        <Basic_Information>

            <Name> James Bond</Name>

            <Address>
                <Number > 05 </Number>
                <Street> Queen's street </Street>
                <Town> London </Town>
            </Address>

            <Phone_Number> 07876543210 </Phone_Number>

        </Basic_Information>

        <Photo> James.png </Photo>

        <Skills_Enable>
            <Skill_1> XML </Skill_1>
            <Skill_2> C# </Skill_2>
        </Skills_Enable>

    </Employe>

    <Employe>

        <ID> 1236 </ID>

        <Basic_Information>

            <Name> Sherlock Holmes </Name>

            <Address>
                <Number > 100 </Number>
                <Street> Prince's street </Street>
                <Town> London </Town>
            </Address>

            <Phone_Number> 07765432100 </Phone_Number>

        </Basic_Information>

        <Photo> Sherlock.png </Photo>

        <Skills_Enable>
            <Skill_1> JavaScript </Skill_1>
            <Skill_2> Python </Skill_2>
        </Skills_Enable>

    </Employe>


 </List_Of_Employe>
```

And here is my **XSL** code (which is wrong ) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

    <h2>List of Workers</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th rowspan="3"> ID </th>
            <th colspan="5"> Basic Information </th>
            <th rowspan="3"> Picture </th>
            <th colspan="2"> Skills enable </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> Name </td>
            <td colspan="3"> Address </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Phone Number </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Skill 1 </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> Skill 2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Number </td>
            <td> Street </td>
            <td> Town </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="List_Of_Employe/Employe">
        <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Number"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Street"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Address/Town"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Basic_Information/Phone_Number"/></td>
            <td><xsl:template match="Photo">
                <xsl:element name="img">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Skills_Enable/Skill_1"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Skills_Enable/Skill_2"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hoping you will be able to help me

Mayeul

Comment: Make it clear that this relates to your [very recent last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450794/display-xml-and-xslt-in-a-browser). I am not sure you are going to benefit from answers here. How about studying the basics of XSLT first? For example, look at what templates are for. There are many good online tutorials on XSLT.

Comment: I have readen the tutorial of the w3c for the xslt already

Comment: Content from W3Schools has absolutely nothing to do with W3C. [This introduction to XSLT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-introxslt/x-introxslt.html) is an example of more useful sources of information.

Comment: thank you for the documentation 
So w3c aren't good tutorial ?

Comment: I am not sure you understand what I am saying. As I said, W3Schools is not operated by the W3C - and is generally frowned upon in the web community. On the other hand, the W3C is the organization developing standards - and their information is very reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention, you can't have a template inside another template. What you should do though is more your `Photo` template outside the main template, and use `xsl:apply-templates` in it's place instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Photo"/>
```

As a simplified example, consider this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>List of Workers</h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th> ID </th>
                  <th> Picture </th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="List_Of_Employe/Employe">
                  <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Photo"/>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Photo">
      <xsl:element name="img">
         <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually, your `Photo` template can be simplified as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="Photo">
    <img src="{.}"></img>
</xsl:template>
```

The use of curly braces here is known as "Attribute Value Templates"

The use of templates is usually preferred in XSLT. If nothing else, if helps reduce indentation! For example, try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>List of Workers</h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th> ID </th>
                  <th> Picture </th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="List_Of_Employe/Employe">
                  <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
               </xsl:apply-templates>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Employe">
       <tr>
           <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
           </td>
           <td>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="Photo"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="Photo">
      <img src="{.}"></img>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```